# RunDLL and Regsvr32 Exploits - how to mitigate or stop?

Tags: malware, malware-removal, malware-detection, rundll32.exe, regsvr32

I have installed Malwarebytes and Spyhunter 5 and run full scans and yet Malwarebytes still shows blocked calls to nefarious domains and IPs via regsvr32 and rundll32. Is there a way to find the source of these calls or are they embedded in the executables now?

At least Malwarebytes is blocking them now.

[image]

Here you see MalwwareBytes actively blocking connection attempts to known malware sites. After a full scan, there shouldn't be a possibility of this as all malware files should be gone. Is there some way of manipulating those two files to continually send HTTP requests?

Here is the rundll32 blocked.

[image]

Yopu can see the IP is a C&C server

I am a super user and don't need hand holding if that helps.

https://attack.mitre.org/techniques/T1218/010/ - it is a known attack vector.

Comment: Back up files and do a clean install, this is the only sure way to rid the PC of the malware.

Comment: It should be pointed out that, you have a malicious software running on your machine, that is throwing these notifications. While it's possible that the files themselves could be compromised, it's more likely, they are just being flagged due to the network behavior that is happening on your device itself.

Comment: Thanks, I know I have malware, and this is the only sign of it so i was wondering was there a way to dump the rundll32 logs to see what's making the calls.